# Excel - Referring to a certain cell based off of data in another

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, cells

I have a spreadsheet where there is one table with the headings:

```
Coordinate, Lat, Long
```

Another with headings

```
Triangle, Coordinate 1, Coordinate 2, Coordinate 3, Area
```

What this is for, is taking the triangles formed by the specified three coordinates' area based off of Girard's theorem, as they are all spherical triangles. I need to take the specific latitude and longitude values from the first table based on the coordinate numbers underneath the three coordinate headings in the second table. I hope this makes sense. Here are pictures detailing what the two tables look like:

**Table 1**

[image: Table 1]

**Table 2**

[image: Table 2]

Thanks in advance. And I really do hope this makes sense.

Comment: Hi Ethan. You're looking to put a calculation in the last column that references the given Coordinates? Can you tell us what the calculation is? It'll make it much easier to recommend a formula.

Comment: Well, the formula is kind of complicated but ok. Area = R^2 * E
Where R = the radius of the triangle and E = the spherical excess which is defined by A+B+C - pi where A,B,C are points on the spherical triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple way to do what I want. Use the `INDIRECT` function as follows:

```
INDIRECT("B"&TEXT(F2+1, "00")))
INDIRECT("C"&TEXT(F2+1, "00")))
```

for coordinate 1 on triangle 1 latitude and longitude respectively.

Hope this helps anyone with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It does make sense.. but what are you trying to do? To calculate the "area" ?

I'm assuming (for now) that you know the formula and you just need to get the "Lat" and "Long" based on the "Coordinate1", "Coordinate2" and "Coordinate3" that refers back to the Table1 Coordinate reference?

You can use 2 VLOOKUP to grab each Coordinate Long and Lat as below:

Long:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet1!A2:C18,2)
```

Lat:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet1!A2:C18,3)
```

Reference:

- B2 refers to Coordinate1 location
- Sheet1!A2:C18 refers to Table1 Array with the data you needed (it can be on the same sheet, just different location - change as needed)
- The last bit (2 and 3) picks and returns the correct column based on the matching Coordinate1 (for this example)

So now you got the Long and Lat for Coordinate 1, you can do the same formula for Coordinate2 - simply change B2 to B3 (or whatever other cell you use) and for Coordinate3 as well.

From there, you got the values for all Long and Lat, I am assuming you can work with your formula from there.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have built tables, you should use the built-in table names in conjunction with vlookup to pull the coordinates. Exactly how those coordinates fit into the calculation you need is something I can't help with (over my head!).

Latitude

```
=VLOOKUP([Coordinate 1],Table1,2,FALSE)
```

Longitude (change column reference from 2 to 3)

```
=VLOOKUP([Coordinate 1],Table1,3,FALSE)
```

Lat for 2nd Coordinate

```
=VLOOKUP([Coordinate 2],Table1,2,FALSE)
```

etc